# Flutter ScrollPhysics that emulate nextPage() and previousPage() in PageController

Tags: flutter

OK -- here is the issue first.  In our app we have a set of screens (5) that the user can walk through to fill out a complex form.  We use a PageView for this.  We also have "Prior/Next" buttons as appropriate that invoke the page controller .nextPage() and .previousPage().  Everything works great if they use that.

However, if the user swipes .. and swipes quickly -- all heck breaks loose.  Basically focus isn't properly set on the "resulting" page if they swipe fast -- actually no focus is set on the page at all even though there is an explicit FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus()  .. with and without a timer ..

What appears to be happening via lots of print() debug statements is when the user swipes fast -- it overshoots the intended page by a bit.. and causes the NEXT NEXT page to start building .. but then pops back to the desired page .. but since each page has a FocusScope .. it appears that the Focus is all screwed up on the end resultant page .. and no focus is set.

But -- on a slow swipe (and hence no overscroll) all works.  And of course the buttons always work since by definition it does one page quanta at a time..

I have tried every ScrollPhysics option .. and none work (except the odious NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() which is very user unfriendly since it doesn't allow any swipes and sometimes the buttons are hidden by the keyboard) ..

I would have thought the PageScrollPhysics would do the trick but nope..

I will grant you that there are some options in the ScrollPhysics etc that I don't fully understand so maybe one of these ScrollPhysics with the proper parameters will do what I want .. (or so I hope!)

So I am hoping someone has run into this and has some ideas/solutions?? I'm pretty much at wits end..

Oh and of course -- it may not be a ScrollPhysics solution .. that's just a guess on my part on how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the issue with  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics ?

Comment: See my comment -- just added it.

Comment: use NeverScrollableScrollPhysics for your pageview and add a SingleChildScrollView inside that to avoid the keyboard issues

Comment: If there is no other solution I will do that @diegoveloper but I don't consider that very clean (the user may have to scroll UP quite a ways to get to the button depending on the device) -- and I would think there is a more elegant method?

Comment: SingleChildScrollView or ListView could help for that

Comment: Still requires the user to scroll up .. to hit a button -- instead of just scrolling left/right .. <shrug> ..